# OOP - how much should I develop classes?

Tags: php, class, oop

I've just started using classes, leaving procedural programming in the past.
But there are some doubts I have while I'm moving forward.

1 - As I wrote in the title, how much should I develop classes?

What I've got so far is, for the register/login sections of a site, this developed classes:

- data access layer (called from almost every class)
- register (validates form and sends email with activation code)
- user login
- activation (checks code / sends new email with new code)
- pass recovery (checks recovery code / sends new email with new code / processes new password form)
- pass encryption (called from register and pass recovery and uses bcrypt)

For example: 
- both in register, activation and recovery, I send emails.. should I create a class "mailing"?
- in register, login, activation, recovery I use tokens and captcha.. same question..

Do you understand what I'm asking?

2- On other hand, I'll create a session after user logs in.
I'll have to retrieve user information such as: Username, Id, Credits, history of operations, ads (created by the user and other ones stored but created by others)..

I can't figure out the way to start.. I should create classes for example:
- Personal info (updates)
- Operations
- Credits
- Ads (a class for those he creates and other one for those he'd like to store)

I'm really confused and I haven't found clear information about how to organize each stage/section..

Comment: What is your requirement ? Still not understand what you are trying to say.. ? you are planning to move ur project to OOPS based concept or what ?

Comment: I'd have **one** `User` class with `Register`, `Login`, `ChangePassword`, `Recovery`, `EncryptPassword` functions, etc. etc. Yes, you should have class for mailing. Add a factory to it, so you can send mails using `Mail_Factory::Get()->SendEmail('a@b.com');`.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at design patterns like MVC, DDD, etc.

Comment: @h2ooooooo is that an answer ? it looks like one, smells like one, but definitively is not placed as one.

Comment: @Prix As far as I'm concerned OP asked how many classes should be made, and then mentioned register/login as an example. This is where my answer points towards. A class that could do just that. Of course this `User` class would have nothing to do with Operations, Credits, Mails or Ads.

Comment: @h2ooooooo then make it an answer and not a comment ?

Comment: @Prix If I made an answer, I'd feel a huge obligation to provide many details, more researched info, examples of code etc. etc., and as it is right now, I do not have time for such. Hence a quick answer in the comments-box. It's really not unusual.

Comment: If you have a conceptual question, you should ask it on [programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I created a site using procedural programming, but while I was reading and learning I realised I should have done it in OOP, so I'm rewriting everything back..

MVC? I'll look for it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the way you want to do the whole website. For big webs, it turns necessary to use a [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) framework ([Zend](http://framework.zend.com/), [Symfony](http://symfony.com/), [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/), [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/), [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/), each one with pros and cons, as always depends on your needs).

In those cases, anything related to database goes into a model, which leaves the [DBAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_abstraction_layer) to the MVC engine, letting you use database objects as classes.

Anything that is in the representation layer (that means, anything that shows information in one or another way) is a view, which is nothing more, nothing less, than an HTML file with some `echo` calls to parameters, or template variables, in case you want to use a template system like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

Anything related to how things are done in your system is a Controller's action, which fits in a Controller, another class, also abstracting the way to do things.

And in the cases you want to validate inputs, treat sessions, etc, it actually depends on the framework you use. In my case, I'm used to Yii, which lets you create something called Components (again classes) to manage stuff that will definitely be reused in other projects.

Each class (Component, Model, Controller, etc) extends a different parent class, so, despite all of them are classes, each one has special methods that make them more practical to do some tasks.

As you see, almost everything can be a class, and it depends on your needs, your framework choices, and your style, on how to code them.

Comment: wow.. I thought that cakephp and others serve to optimize/organize tasks and process of an app.. But as I was learning oop, I thought I should get familiar with programming the classes first..

Comment: Learning OOP is the very first step to use MVC. Of course you should code a little, gain experience, learn the syntax (so you can find possible mistakes easily and extend your own classes), know the pros and cons of using classes, and **then** you are good to go with MVC. My answer was just a hint that you don't need to rethink everything, as almost everything is already done, thought and rethought. If you feel my answer is what you were looking for, don't forget to accept it, clicking in the tick mark next to the answer's votes.

Comment: yes, I agree.. I've suspended what I was doing a couple months ago, and started reading and learning about classes. Everything was about what are classes, how to develop, use, extend them.. But very few good articles I found about organization.. I'll keep digging about it and then I'll start with MVC.. thanks for your time! greetings from Argentina

Comment: You're welcome, from/desde Barcelona ;)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to have a look on MVC like cakephp, zend framework, if you want to apply oop concepts. Download cakephp http://cakephp.org/

Comment: Thanks, I've started digging about it..